# getElementByName returns Type Error?

Tags: javascript, checked, unchecked

My code:

```
var isSomethingChecked = (document.getElementByName("koalaCheck").checked ||
                          document.getElementByName("kangarooCheck").checked);
```

Why does this code throw an exception called "Type Error"?

Comment: Because getElementByName is probably returning null.

Comment: A TypeError is most commonly thrown when you try to access a value that is unexpectedly null or undefined. A TypeError can also be thrown if you use the operator on a value that is not a constructor or if you pass too many arguments to a built-in function.

Comment: @zzzzBov Or because the method doesn't exist...

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: @RaymondChen Good point, changed it so it hopefully helps

Comment: @RaymondChen Although, I'm not sure that's a reason to close the question

Comment: @ian, right forgot that that method was plural as i never use it.

Comment: @zzzzBov Haha me either...

Comment: @Ian "Unlikely to be useful to others" is listed as one of the grounds for closure as "too localized".

Comment: @RaymondChen I understand that, but that's referring to the **question**, not the **title**. The question could be plenty useful to others. There's no reason to be so quick to judge

Comment: @Ian I used to fix the titles but then I realized that I was just giving somebody a fish rather than forcing them to pick up a rod and reel. Even if the question is useful, a vague title will prevent anybody from finding it in the future.

Comment: @RaymondChen You're absolutely right about that. I guess it makes sense to do to "scare" people, I just can't help but fix the title or hope that the OP sees a comment pointing out the flaw :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no function called `getElementByName`. what you need is `getElementsByName` which returns an array of all of the elements that have that name. so you can use:

```
var isSomethingChecked = (document.getElementsByName("koalaCheck")[0].checked ||    
                         document.getElementsByName("kangarooCheck")[0].checked);
```

Comment: A little explanation of what you changed would be useful.

Comment: so can you do something like this? var isSomethingChecked = (document.getElementsByName("koalaCheck", "kangarooCheck").checked)

Comment: @jfriend00 - What was changed is the function name has an "S" added to it at the end of Elements since getElementsByName could return more than 1 & getElementById will only return one so for Name the Elements is plural. Good answer Omar Jackman I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 4):

That would be because the correct method is `document.getElementsByName()`.  You missed an s.

View the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName).

Assuming you do not wish to check each checked state per element(as this method returns an array)..  I would use `document.getElementById()`..  but that is without seeing your html.

Comment: And `getElementsByName()` returns an array not a single element.  I didn't downvote, but you only got part of the answer right.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for the note..  I have edited to leave a note in that regard, though without seeing the html or the intended action I believe anything further would be shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of all elements with the given name.  You either need to use the `getElementById` function or specify a particular element in the returned array like so:

```
var isSomethingChecked = (document.getElementsByName("koalaCheck")[0].checked || document.getElementsByName("kangarooCheck")[0].checked);
```

You get the "Type Error" because you are checking whether an array is checked instead of a particular element.